# In async wait where to display error message for user

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, async-await

I have code like below to fetch a photo from azure. When i get an error that no image is available i catch the error and error.log it. however this looks ugly. what is a better way of showing this? i can;'t redirect as this to a 404 as this error doesn't stop the app from working

```
fetchImage = async(token) => {
        try {
          const response = await axios
            .get(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${this.props.authentication._user.userName}/photo/$value`,{
              responseType: 'arraybuffer',
              headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
            })

            this.setState({
              image: new Buffer(response.data).toString('base64')
            })
        }
        catch (error) {
          console.error(error)
        }
      }
```

Comment: You could use `this.setState` inside your `catch` block as well, but have a separate state variable e.g. `error`. You can then check if `error` has a value in the render method and render it.

Answer (score 0):

you can make new prop on state for example isError

---

and then you can controll error wtih that prop 
**(isError) ? : "received error" : "keep continue"**

```
state = {
  isError: false
};

fetchImage = async token => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${
        this.props.authentication._user.userName
      }/photo/$value`,
      {
        responseType: "arraybuffer",
        headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + token }
      }
    );

    this.setState({
      image: new Buffer(response.data).toString("base64")
    });
  } catch (error) {
    this.setState({
      isError: true
    });
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

if you need save error message you can do this

```
state = {
  error: ""
};

in the catch block 

catch (error) {
  this.setState({
    error: error.message
  });
}

and then check (this.state.error.length) ? "show error" : 'continue working'
```